# Envelope Allow Markup not Working

Tags: docusignapi

Per the documentation one of the properties of an envelope is a boolean 'allowMarkup'. I assume this works in conjunction with the settings property located at Preferences >> Account Administration >> Features >> "Allow Markup". I have this option check and I've created a new envelope with the following json:

```
{
  "allowMarkup": true,
  "emailBlurb": "Allow Markup Test",
  "emailSubject": "Test envelope that should allow to modify docs."
}
```

After I create the envelope I see the following check box is not checked in the UI :

[image]

It seems that i can only set the highlighted property from the UI. Bug? Can anyone reproduce this?  We are testing this in sandbox as an FYI.

-mike

Comment: Just curious, does it work if you pass the value with quotes around it?  Right now you have this `"allowMarkup": true,`, does this work `"allowMarkup": "true",` ?

Comment: No, that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Just to following up on this: This was a issue was reproduced by DocuSign support and has been assigned to engineering for resolution.